# Powerbuild Dateobject to java

Tags: java, vbscript, data-objects

i am doing a task converting VB script written from Powerbuild to java,

i am  struggled at converting the DataStore Object into java ,

i have something like this :

```
lds_appeal_application = Create DataStore
lds_appeal_application.DataObject = "ds_appeal_application_report"
lds_appeal_application.SetTransObject(SQLCA)

ll_row = lds_appeal_application.retrieve(as_ksdyh, adt_start_date, adt_end_date, as_exam_name, as_subject_code)

for ll_rc = 1 to ll_row
ldt_update_date = lds_appeal_application.GetItemDatetime(ll_rc, "sqsj")
ls_caseno = trim(lds_appeal_application.GetItemString(ll_rc, "caseno"))
ls_candidate_no = trim(lds_appeal_application.GetItemString(ll_rc, "zkzh"))
ls_subjectcode = trim(lds_appeal_application.GetItemString(ll_rc, "kmcode"))
ls_papercode = trim(lds_appeal_application.GetItemString(ll_rc, "papercode"))
ls_name = trim(lds_appeal_application.GetItemString(ll_rc, "mc"))
ll_ksh = lds_appeal_application.GetItemDecimal(ll_rc, "ks_h")
ll_kmh = lds_appeal_application.GetItemDecimal(ll_rc, "km_h")
```

simply speaking, a datasoure is created and a data table is point to it by sql query(ds_appeal_application_report). Finally  using a for loop to retrieve information from the table.

in java way of doing, i use an entities manager to createnativequery and the query can result a list of object array. However, i just dont know how to retrieve the information like VB using the DataStore Object.

please give me some advice . Thanks

Comment: VBScript is not VB.NET. Please choose tags carefully to get the appropriate answer